# Fit to screen from different Orthographic camera positions

Tags: three.js, rotation

Made a simple [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/19/) to illustrate a problem.
I'm trying to fit object's bounding box to screen from different camera positions. In example in dat.GUI panel you can change camera position and then click button fit to screen.

When changing y and z (positive) camera positions to find camera's top and bottom properties code below is used

```
var top = boundingBox.max.y * Math.cos(angleToZAxis) + boundingBox.max.z * Math.sin(angleToZAxis); // line 68
var bottom boundingBox.min.y * Math.cos(angleToZAxis) + boundingBox.min.z * Math.sin(angleToZAxis);
```

I would like to know how I can include camera's x position and negative positions in this calculation, what is the math behind this. Should I use rotation matrix and how to use it?

Or maybe it can be achieved in some simple way with threejs methods, can't figure out, tried the code below but something is wrong:

```
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();   
matrix.lookAt ( this.camera.position, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0) );  
var bbMax = boundingBox.max.clone().applyMatrix4(matrix);
var bbMin = boundingBox.min.clone().applyMatrix4(matrix)
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fit an orthographic camera you have to simply change its zoom and position

you can calculate zoom from the bounding box of your object

(I used the boxes from geometry, but you will have to take in account matrices of the objects in group; I used them because .setFromObject was not returning consistent value)

```
Canvas3D.prototype.fitToScreen = function() {    
    this.group.children[0].geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    var boundingBox = this.group.children[0].geometry.boundingBox.clone();
    this.group.children[1].geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    boundingBox.union(this.group.children[1].geometry.boundingBox);
    var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation(this.camera.matrix);    
    boundingBox.applyMatrix4(rotation);
    this.camera.zoom = Math.min(this.winWidth / (boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x),
              this.winHeight / (boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y)) * 0.95;

    this.camera.position.copy(boundingBox.center());   
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();   
    this.camera.updateMatrix();
};
```

using this will not work in your fiddle because you are using OrbitControls and they rotate camera on update based on their own state - so either update that state or create your own controls

also either move camera back after

```
this.camera.position.copy(boundingBox.center());
```

or set near plane to -1000 to avoid having cut object

```
this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(this.winWidth  / -2, 
    this.winWidth  / 2   , this.winHeight / 2, this.winHeight / -2, -10000, 10000);
```

EDIT 
now i see that you dont want to just fit the object but the whole box...
to do so an easy way is to project the points of the box and get the distances of extremes in pixels, then you can set ortho camera directly

```
boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.group);
//take all 8 vertices of the box and project them
var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.min.x,boundingBox.min.y,boundingBox.min.z).project(this.camera);
var p2 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.min.x,boundingBox.min.y,boundingBox.max.z).project(this.camera);
var p3 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.min.x,boundingBox.max.y,boundingBox.min.z).project(this.camera);
var p4 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.min.x,boundingBox.max.y,boundingBox.max.z).project(this.camera);

var p5 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.max.x,boundingBox.min.y,boundingBox.min.z).project(this.camera);
var p6 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.max.x,boundingBox.min.y,boundingBox.max.z).project(this.camera);
var p7 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.max.x,boundingBox.max.y,boundingBox.min.z).project(this.camera);
var p8 = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.max.x,boundingBox.max.y,boundingBox.max.z).project(this.camera);
//fill a box to get the extremes of the 8 points
var box = new THREE.Box3();
box.expandByPoint(p1);
box.expandByPoint(p2);
box.expandByPoint(p3);
box.expandByPoint(p4);
box.expandByPoint(p5);
box.expandByPoint(p6);
box.expandByPoint(p7);
box.expandByPoint(p8);
//take absolute value because the points already have the correct sign
var top = box.max.y * Math.abs(this.camera.top);
var bottom = box.min.y * Math.abs(this.camera.bottom);    

var right = box.max.x * Math.abs(this.camera.right);
var left = box.min.x *  Math.abs(this.camera.left);   
this.updateCamera(left, right, top, bottom);
```

this code also stretches the view to fit exactly into the window so you will have to check for the aspect ratio and change one size accordingly, but that should be trivial

Comment: Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/23/)  with new code and disabled Orbitcontrols. I think it's facing same problem as my try to calculate top/bottom/left/right parameters. Bounding box corners not always visible with different camera positions. I would like to fit bounding box in screen without 0.95 factor if possible. Is something wrong in my updated fiddle code? Thanks.

Comment: Borrowed one idea from your code and added to my. Instead of trying to calculate rotation, I took camera rotation. That fixed negative position problem but still cutting corners. [Updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/24/)